# JavaScript object and datatype

Tags: javascript

I am confused why the following does not evaluate to true.
How do I compare whether two objects are the same?

```
var x = new Object();
var y = {};
x == y // false

function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

var p1 = new Person("Chris");
var p2 = new Person("Chris");
p1 == p2 // false
```

Comment: @bencripps that question is already closed as a duplicate of the one I've voted to close it as.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly sure, I just think the answer provided in the first link is better.

Answer (score 2):

Without going into how a JS engine works you can understand it by just thinking of it like objects are in the real world. If `x` is a ball and `y` is a chair, they aren't equal just because they are both objects. And if you know two people named `Chris` they aren't the same person they just have the same name.